# How can I construct a process for cumulative returns that is riskless?

Tags: finance, risk, probability, autoregressive

This question is a little more specific than the title. Here I use the same notation that is set forth in [this other question about cumulative returns](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/formula-for-the-unconditional-variance-of-the-sum-of-observations-from-an-autore) (the sum of return observations). That is, let $r_{t,t+n} = \sum_{i=1}^n r_{t+i}$. Suppose that $r_t$ is an AR(1) process (say with Normally distributed errors) where
$$
\text{Cov}(r_t,r_{t+j}) = \rho^j \sigma^2
$$
and thus
$$
\text{Corr}(r_t, r_{t+j}) = \rho^j.
$$
In the same notes references in the other question I see a claim that when $\rho = -1$
that the cumulative return is riskless, i.e.,
$$
\text{Var}(r_{t,t+n}) = 0.
$$
How can this be? For example, if I let define the AR(1) process as follows
$$
r_{t+1} = - r_t + \epsilon_{t+1},
$$
then consider the following example:
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(r_{t,t+2}) &= \text{Var}(r_{t+1} + r_{t+2}) \\
 &= \text{Var}(\epsilon_{t+2}),
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(r_{t,t+4}) &= \text{Var}(\epsilon_{t+2} + \epsilon_{t+4}).
\end{align}
So, this doesn't appear to work.

If I define $\sigma^2$ as the unconditional, long-run variance of an observation,
$\text{Var}(r_{t+1}) = \sigma^2$ as I did in the other question ([linked](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/formula-for-the-unconditional-variance-of-the-sum-of-observations-from-an-autore)), then when
$\rho = -1$ this variance doesn't is undetermined/infinite. Am I missing something? Can I reconcile the claim made in these notes?